# Javassist how to invoke method defined in super class

Tags: java, javassist

I have a class NFTypeSerializer and I use javassist create a subclass of NFTypeSerializer

```
    CtClass superCc = pool.get(NFTypeSerializer.class.getName());
    CtClass cc = pool.makeClass("HotelSerializer", superCc);
```

and I want to override a method doSerialize() which is defined in NFTypeSerializer

```
    cc.addMethod(CtNewMethod.make("protected void doSerialize(Hotel value, NFSerializationRecord rec) {\n" +
            "        serializePrimitive(rec, \"name\", value.getName());\n" +
            "        serializePrimitive(rec, \"price\", value.getPrice());\n" +
            "    }", cc));
```

but the error occur

> Exception in thread "main" javassist.CannotCompileException: [source
>   error]
>   serializePrimitive(com.netflix.zeno.serializer.NFSerializationRecord,java.lang.String,double)
>   not found in HotelSerializer  at
>   javassist.CtNewMethod.make(CtNewMethod.java:79)   at
>   javassist.CtNewMethod.make(CtNewMethod.java:45)   at
>   test.demo.javassist.ComponentBuilder.buildHotelSerializer(ComponentBuilder.java:60)
>     at
>   test.demo.javassist.ComponentBuilder.main(ComponentBuilder.java:88)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
>   Caused by: compile error:
>   serializePrimitive(com.netflix.zeno.serializer.NFSerializationRecord,java.lang.String,double)
>   not found in HotelSerializer  at
>   javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(TypeChecker.java:723)
>     at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:688)
>     at
>   javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
>     at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)     at
>   javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:242)  at
>   javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:330)  at
>   javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)    at
>   javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:351)  at
>   javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)    at
>   javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atMethodBody(CodeGen.java:292)     at
>   javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atMethodDecl(CodeGen.java:274)     at
>   javassist.compiler.ast.MethodDecl.accept(MethodDecl.java:44)  at
>   javassist.compiler.Javac.compileMethod(Javac.java:169)    at
>   javassist.compiler.Javac.compile(Javac.java:95)   at
>   javassist.CtNewMethod.make(CtNewMethod.java:74)   ... 8 more

the method serializePrimitive() is defined in super class but I can't invoke it in CtNewMethod ?

Comment: Please check the constructors declared for `serializePrimitive()`. You might be passing the wrong types of values or in the wrong sequence.

Comment: @CrakC you are right! the declaration is "serializePrimitive(NFSerializationRecord rec, String fieldName, Object value)" and I have to invoke it in this way "serializePrimitive(rec, "price", Double.valueOf(value.getPrice()));"

Comment: Alright so according to the header, the third parameter should be of the type `Object` while you have supplied a `double`.

Comment: @CrakC you are right XD

Comment: Let me post the same as an answer so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the constructors declared for serializePrimitive(). You might be passing the wrong types of values or in the wrong sequence.

**Supplied paramters-**

`serializePrimitive(NFSerializationRecord rec, String fieldName, double value)`

**Expected parameters-**

`serializePrimitive(NFSerializationRecord rec, String fieldName, Object value)`